# How do I display an NSObject, View class within another view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, csv, swiftui

I am trying to read a CSV file. I have made a class that handles this however when the view loads it crashes with the error message: `Thread 1: Fatal error: views must be value types (either a struct or an enum); MyClass is a class.`

Here is my view:

```swift
struct MyView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Some Text")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .bold()
                .padding()
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                MyClass()
                Button {print("hello world")} label: {Text("button text")}
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my class:

```swift
final class MyClass: NSObject, View {
    @State private var selectedFile: URL?
    @State private var showAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            let supportedTypes: [UTType] = [.commaSeparatedText]
            let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: supportedTypes)
            documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = false
            documentPicker.delegate = self
            if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
               let window = windowScene.windows.first {
                window.rootViewController?.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        } label: {
            VStack {
                Text("upload")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 405, height: 120)
        .background(.green)
        .cornerRadius(12)
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Alert(
                title: Text("Invalid CSV File"),
                message: Text("The uploaded file must be a valid CSV file and contain the columns 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', and 'C4'."),
                dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"))
            )
        }
    }
}


extension MyClass: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        guard let selectedFile = urls.first else { return }
        self.selectedFile = selectedFile
        
        do {
            let csvString = try String(contentsOf: selectedFile, encoding: .utf8)
            let rows = csvString.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
            
            let headerRow = rows.first?.components(separatedBy: ",")
            guard headerRow?.contains("C1") ?? false, headerRow?.contains("C2") ?? false, headerRow?.contains("C3") ?? false, headerRow?.contains("C4") ?? false else {
                self.showAlert = true
                return
            }
            print("File uploaded successfully")
        } catch {
            self.showAlert = true
            print("Error uploading file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried applying a MyClassWrapper and calling that in the view instead but kept getting the error: `Type 'MyClassWrapper' does not conform to protocol 'UIViewRepresentable'` and it would not build rather than crash when the view showing the class is reached.
This was the MyClassWrapper code I tried:

```swift
struct MyClassWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = MyClass
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MyClass {
        return MyClass()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MyClass, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Like the message says views are not classes there is no such thing as a view that is an NSObject. You have to restructure likely include a StateObject that is an ObservableObject so you can have the delegate.

Comment: SwiftUI views are structs, period. You have to wrap the `UIDocumentPickerViewController` in a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` for example as described here: https://maheshsai252.medium.com/document-handling-in-swiftui-664cf050c724

Comment: @vadian there's already a built-in modifier called `fileImporter`, which uses the same `UIDocumentPicker` under the hood, available since iOS 14

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, the app crashes with this error `Thread 1: Fatal error: views must be value types (either a struct or an enum); MyClass is a class.`, which basically means that all `View`s must be structures(aka value types)

So first you need to make `MyClass` a structure, and remove inheritance to `NSObject`, like this:

```swift
struct MyClass: View {
    @State private var selectedFile: URL?
    @State private var showAlert = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            let supportedTypes: [UTType] = [.commaSeparatedText]
            let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: supportedTypes)
            documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = false
            documentPicker.delegate = self
            if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
               let window = windowScene.windows.first {
                window.rootViewController?.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        } label: {
            VStack {
                Text("upload")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 405, height: 120)
        .background(.green)
        .cornerRadius(12)
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Alert(
                title: Text("Invalid CSV File"),
                message: Text("The uploaded file must be a valid CSV file and contain the columns 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', and 'C4'."),
                dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"))
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to use `SwiftUI` equivalent to `UIDocumentPicker`(because it's basically impossible to assign delegate properly in `View`, delegate needs to be a reference type, not a value type, which `View` is), which is [fileImporter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu/fileimporter(ispresented:allowedcontenttypes:allowsmultipleselection:oncompletion:)), available from `iOS 14`

This is the final code:

```swift
struct MyClass: View {
    @State private var selectedFile: URL?
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @State private var fileImporterPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            fileImporterPresented = true
        } label: {
            VStack {
                Text("upload")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 405, height: 120)
        .background(.green)
        .cornerRadius(12)
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $fileImporterPresented,
                      allowedContentTypes: [.commaSeparatedText]) { result in
            if case let .success(url) = result {
                // verify&upload your CSV file
            }
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Alert(
                title: Text("Invalid CSV File"),
                message: Text("The uploaded file must be a valid CSV file and contain the columns 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', and 'C4'."),
                dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"))
            )
        }
    }
}
```